# Определить, каким будет следующее значение

Tags: javascript, jquery

Есть скрипт, задача которого прибавлять или убавлять числовое значение в инпуте. И работа скрипта должна быть организована так, что в случае, если достигнуто минимальное значение, то кнопка "минус" становится неактивной. Это же правило равносильно и для кнопки "плюс". Но работает скрипт криво - когда достигнуто минимальное значение, то на кнопку нужно нажать ещё раз и только тогда она станет неактивной. Как это исправить? Пробовал уменьшать пределы значений - не помогает.

HTML:

```
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons"
   rel="stylesheet">
<div class="lists-content">
   <div class="list-item">
      <span class="list-name" data-description="Старше 12 лет">Взрослые</span>
      <div class="numeric-selector">
         <a class="minus disabled"><i class="material-icons">remove</i></a>
         <input type="number" class="numeric-input" min="1" max="9" readonly="" value="1">
         <a class="plus"><i class="material-icons">add</i></a>
      </div>
   </div>
   <div class="list-item">
      <span class="list-name" data-description="От 2 до 12 лет">Подростки</span>
      <div class="numeric-selector">
         <a class="minus disabled"><i class="material-icons">remove</i></a>
         <input type="number" class="numeric-input" min="0" max="9" readonly="" value="0">
         <a class="plus"><i class="material-icons">add</i></a>
      </div>
   </div>
   <div class="list-item">
      <span class="list-name" data-description="До 2 лет">Младенцы</span>
      <div class="numeric-selector">
         <a class="minus disabled"><i class="material-icons">remove</i></a>
         <input type="number" class="numeric-input" min="0" max="9" readonly="" value="0">
         <a class="plus"><i class="material-icons">add</i></a>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
body {
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  width: 200px
}
.lists-content {
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
    z-index: 12;
    background: #fff;
    padding: 18px;
    border-radius: 4px;
}
.lists-content > .list-item {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0 0 12px;
}
.lists-content > .list-item:last-child {
    margin: 0;
}
.lists-content > .list-item > .list-name {
    position: relative;
    font-size: 0.825rem;
    float: left;
    display: inline-block;
    text-align: left;
}
.lists-content > .list-item > .list-name:after {
    position: relative;
    content: attr(data-description);
    font-size: 0.6rem;
    display: block;
    color: #9e9e9e;
}
.lists-content > .list-item > .numeric-selector {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    float: right;
    font-size: 0;
    padding: 2px 0;
    -webkit-touch-callout: none;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    -moz-user-select: none;
    -ms-user-select: none;
}
.lists-content > .list-item > .numeric-selector a {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    cursor: pointer;
    width: 24px;
    height: 24px;
    color: #e0e0e0;
    -webkit-transition: all .25s;
    transition: all .25s;
}
.lists-content > .list-item > .numeric-selector a i {
    font-size: 22px;
}
.lists-content > .list-item > .numeric-selector a.minus {
    border-radius: 2px 0 0 2px;
    border: 1px solid #e0e0e0;
}
.lists-content > .list-item > .numeric-selector a.minus:hover {
    border: 1px solid #ef9a9a;
    color: #ef9a9a;
}
.lists-content > .list-item > .numeric-selector a.minus.disabled:hover {
    border-radius: 2px 0 0 2px;
    border: 1px solid #e0e0e0;
    color: #e0e0e0;
    cursor: default;
}
.lists-content > .list-item > .numeric-selector a.plus {
    border: 1px solid #e0e0e0;
    border-radius: 0 2px 2px 0;
}
.lists-content > .list-item > .numeric-selector a.plus:hover {
    border: 1px solid #8bc34a;
    color: #8bc34a;
}
.lists-content > .list-item > .numeric-selector a.plus.disabled:hover {
    border: 1px solid #e0e0e0;
    border-radius: 0 2px 2px 0;
    color: #e0e0e0;
    cursor: default;
}
.lists-content > .list-item > .numeric-selector input {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    outline: 0;
    width: 24px;
    height: 24px;
    font-size: 14px;
    text-align: center;
    border-left: 0;
    border-right: 0;
    border-top: 1px solid #e0e0e0;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #e0e0e0;
    margin-top: -22px;
    vertical-align: middle;
    z-index: 1;
    -moz-appearance: textfield;
}
```

JS:

```
$(function NumericOperations() {
    var input = $('.numeric-input');
    var minus = input.prev('a.minus');
    var plus = input.next('a.plus');

    minus.html(function() {
        var min = $(this).next(input).attr('min');
        if($(this).next(input).val() == min) {
            $(this).addClass('disabled');
        };
    });

    plus.on('click', function() {
        var max = $(this).prev(input).attr('max');
        if($(this).prev(input).val() == max) {
            $(this).addClass('disabled');
        };
    });

    minus.on('click', function() {
        var min = $(this).next(input).attr('min');
        if($(this).next(input).val() !== min) {
            var current_int = parseInt($(this).next(input).val(), 10);
            $(this).next(input).val(--current_int);
            $(this).parents('.numeric-selector').find('a').removeClass('disabled');
        } else {
            $(this).addClass('disabled');
        }
    });

    plus.on('click', function() {
        var max = $(this).prev(input).attr('max');
        if($(this).prev(input).val() !== max) {
            var current_int = parseInt($(this).prev(input).val(), 10);
            $(this).prev(input).val(++current_int);
            $(this).parents('.numeric-selector').find('a').removeClass('disabled');
        } else {
            $(this).addClass('disabled');
        }
    });
});
```

Пример работы на jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/euk328n7/1/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

При достижении максимума или минимума не заходит в `else`:

```js
$(function NumericOperations() {
  var input = $('.numeric-input');
  var minus = input.prev('a.minus');
  var plus = input.next('a.plus');

 

  plus.on('click', function() {
    var max = $(this).prev(input).attr('max');
    if ($(this).prev(input).val() == max) {
      $(this).addClass('disabled');
    };
  });

  minus.on('click', function() {
    var min = $(this).next(input).attr('min');
    if ($(this).next(input).val() !== min) {
      var current_int = parseInt($(this).next(input).val(), 10);
      $(this).next(input).val(--current_int);
      $(this).parents('.numeric-selector').find('a').removeClass('disabled');
    } 
    if ($(this).next(input).val() == min) {
      $(this).addClass('disabled');
    }
  });

  plus.on('click', function() {
    var max = $(this).prev(input).attr('max');
    if ($(this).prev(input).val() != max) {
      var current_int = parseInt($(this).prev(input).val(), 10);
      $(this).prev(input).val(++current_int);
      $(this).parents('.numeric-selector').find('a').removeClass('disabled');
    }
    if($(this).prev(input).val() == max) {
      $(this).addClass('disabled');
    }
  });
});
```

```css
body {
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  width: 200px
}

.lists-content {
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  z-index: 12;
  background: #fff;
  padding: 18px;
  border-radius: 4px;
}

.lists-content > .list-item {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0 0 12px;
}

.lists-content > .list-item:last-child {
  margin: 0;
}

.lists-content > .list-item > .list-name {
  position: relative;
  font-size: 0.825rem;
  float: left;
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: left;
}

.lists-content > .list-item > .list-name:after {
  position: relative;
  content: attr(data-description);
  font-size: 0.6rem;
  display: block;
  color: #9e9e9e;
}

.lists-content > .list-item > .numeric-selector {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  float: right;
  font-size: 0;
  padding: 2px 0;
  -webkit-touch-callout: none;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
}

.lists-content > .list-item > .numeric-selector a {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  cursor: pointer;
  width: 24px;
  height: 24px;
  color: #e0e0e0;
  -webkit-transition: all .25s;
  transition: all .25s;
}

.lists-content > .list-item > .numeric-selector a i {
  font-size: 22px;
}

.lists-content > .list-item > .numeric-selector a.minus {
  border-radius: 2px 0 0 2px;
  border: 1px solid #e0e0e0;
}

.lists-content > .list-item > .numeric-selector a.minus:hover {
  border: 1px solid #ef9a9a;
  color: #ef9a9a;
}

.lists-content > .list-item > .numeric-selector a.minus.disabled:hover {
  border-radius: 2px 0 0 2px;
  border: 1px solid #e0e0e0;
  color: #e0e0e0;
  cursor: default;
}

.lists-content > .list-item > .numeric-selector a.plus {
  border: 1px solid #e0e0e0;
  border-radius: 0 2px 2px 0;
}

.lists-content > .list-item > .numeric-selector a.plus:hover {
  border: 1px solid #8bc34a;
  color: #8bc34a;
}

.lists-content > .list-item > .numeric-selector a.plus.disabled:hover {
  border: 1px solid #e0e0e0;
  border-radius: 0 2px 2px 0;
  color: #e0e0e0;
  cursor: default;
}

.lists-content > .list-item > .numeric-selector input {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  outline: 0;
  width: 24px;
  height: 24px;
  font-size: 14px;
  text-align: center;
  border-left: 0;
  border-right: 0;
  border-top: 1px solid #e0e0e0;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #e0e0e0;
  margin-top: -22px;
  vertical-align: middle;
  z-index: 1;
  -moz-appearance: textfield;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
<div class="lists-content">
  <div class="list-item">
    <span class="list-name" data-description="Старше 12 лет">Взрослые</span>
    <div class="numeric-selector">
      <a class="minus disabled"><i class="material-icons">remove</i></a>
      <input type="number" class="numeric-input" min="1" max="9" readonly="" value="1">
      <a class="plus"><i class="material-icons">add</i></a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="list-item">
    <span class="list-name" data-description="От 2 до 12 лет">Подростки</span>
    <div class="numeric-selector">
      <a class="minus disabled"><i class="material-icons">remove</i></a>
      <input type="number" class="numeric-input" min="0" max="9" readonly="" value="0">
      <a class="plus"><i class="material-icons">add</i></a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="list-item">
    <span class="list-name" data-description="До 2 лет">Младенцы</span>
    <div class="numeric-selector">
      <a class="minus disabled"><i class="material-icons">remove</i></a>
      <input type="number" class="numeric-input" min="0" max="9" readonly="" value="0">
      <a class="plus"><i class="material-icons">add</i></a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/CRafT/euk328n7/2/).

Comment: Пожалуйста, используйте сниппет для примеров, ссылки на сторонние ресурсы могут **дополнять**, но **не быть основными**.